# Reestarting JVM wont reload ehcache objects

Tags: ehcache

I am facing issues with ehcache, I have set my cache to be eternal and I am bouncing the JVM's one by one to "not to have downtime",  and this actually not clearing my ehcache and reloading new objects..

```
<cache name="SampleServerStartupCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true" maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
    diskPersistent="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" />
```

I was having a belief that when the cache is set to eternal="true" the restart of JVM should flush and load the new objects. However in order to avoid downtime, we are bouncing the JVM'S one by one, will that a make difference between a clean restart ?

Answer (score 0):

`eternal="true"` only means that elements will not expire from the cache. It has no impact on the life of elements across a JVM restart.

If you desire persistence of cache elements, you need to set `diskPersistent="true"`, define a disk path in your config file. You must also do a proper shutdown of the `CacheManager` when bouncing the JVM otherwise the data saved on disk might be discarded on restart.

**Added after comment**

In your scenario, restarting a JVM will clear its cache. But loading of the cache will only happen when your application puts to it. Ehcache is not configured to do pre-loading. If that's what you desire, have a look at the documentation on [`BootstrapCacheLoader`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/index.html?net/sf/ehcache/bootstrap/BootstrapCacheLoader.html).

Comment: thanks Louis, So I have to do a complete restart and not by rolling bounce ? hence the ehcache will be cleared ? is that the only option ?

Comment: Hope the edits answers your question - if not, please add clarifications to your question.